# Define Murri in Typescript by RequireJS

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I'm going to use [Murri](https://github.com/haltu/muuri) in my typescript project, I have defined Muuri and its related dependencies in RequireJS config like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {      
        "web-animations-js": "web-animations-js/web-animations.min",
        "hammerjs": "hammerjs/hammer",
        "muuri": "muuri/muuri",
    },
    shim: {       
        "muuri": {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            deps: ["hammerjs", "web-animations-js"],
            exports: 'Muuri'
        }
    }
});

requirejs([ "muuri"]);
```

And in my typescript file I have used something like this:

```
declare var Muuri: any;

export default class WidgetModule {

    public static run() {

        $(function () { //DOM Ready
            //here I get error
            var grid = new Muuri('.grid', { dragEnabled: true });
        });
    }
}
```

But I get the error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Muuri is not defined** .

*Thanks in forward for your help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I have come is to use this

```
import Muuri = require("../lib/muuri/muuri.js");
```

I add it at the top of my Typescript file. Hope it helps someone ;)